# JsonConvert string to integer about digit grouping symbol

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I get an error that is **'Could not convert string to integer: 3.500. Path 'Quantity''** while json converting to object.

json :

```
{"ProductCalcKey":"xxx","PaperType":"1","Quantity":"3.500"}
```

object:

```
public class UnitPrice
{
    public int UnitPriceId { get; set; }
    public int QuantityMin { get; set; }
    public int QuantityMax { get; set; }
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
    public string ProductCalcKey { get; set; }
    public PaperType? PaperType { get; set; }
    public int Quantity { get; set; }
}
```

I am using the following method.

```
protected object FromJsonToObject(Type t)
{
    Context.Request.InputStream.Position = 0;
    string json;
    using (var reader = new StreamReader(Context.Request.InputStream))
    {
        json = reader.ReadToEnd();
    }

    // todo: string to integer such as '222.222.222'
    return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json, t, new IsoDateTimeConverter());
}
```

How can I solve this problem without touching jsontext ?

Comment: Change Quantity from int to string and convert it after Deserialization.

Comment: I cannot do it. This is general structure. I will also use for other things. I cannot touch the json text. I have to solve with json converter.

Comment: I am not sure, but i do not believe that you can do that. I hope someone give you the answer. Me, under that circumstances i don't know but i am also very curious about the answer. I will follow that post to the end. Also +1 for that post.

Comment: There is another my question here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15810087/how-to-format-properties-that-are-only-string-in-an-object-while-converting-to-j. I think can be do in that way. The problems are very similar. But I could not do it. I dont know how to do.

Comment: Correct me if i am wrong but the post you said is about formatting a string field not about converting.

Comment: Yes you are right, it is about a string field. but it has to be solved while converting.

Comment: After a little search i am afraid you can not do that, but this is what i believe which may be wrong. If you find a solution please let me know. Thx

Comment: I have solved it. You can look at.

Comment: It appears that you have locale-dependent formatting of some of your data.  Fix the source to encode it in a locale-independent manner.  Changing the field from String to int (at the source) would resolve this.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I have solved the problem in this way.

```
public class FormatConverter : JsonConverter
{
    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        if (objectType == typeof(int))
        {
            return Convert.ToInt32(reader.Value.ToString().Replace(".", string.Empty));
        }

        return reader.Value;
    }

    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return objectType == typeof(int);
    }
}


[Test]
public void ConvertJson()
{
    const string Json = "{\"ProductCalcKey\":\"xxx\",\"PaperType\":\"1\",\"Quantity\":\"3.500\"}";
    var o = (UnitPrice)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Json, typeof(UnitPrice), new FormatConverter());
    Assert.AreEqual(3500, o.Quantity);
}
```

Comment: You should use `Int32.Parse("3.500", NumberStyles.AllowThousands, CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("it"))` instead of manipulating strings (change `"it"` to the culture used in JSON), it's more architecturally correct.